# Looking to shorten php include paths

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I've created a php login script hosted on a ubunutu server located at /var/www/html/project. However when i include files within my PHP script, i want to be able to be able to use shortened paths such as include project/class.php instead of having to use include var/www/html/project/class.php.

i've used composer .json to generate an autoloader in a vendor folder which uses psr-4. The index.php file is in /var/www/html/project/index.php. My sessions class is in /var/www/html/project/classes/session.php. I just want to be able to say. include classes/session.php

Is there a way to do this and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: If the main file that loads and does the include is in `/var/www/html/project` then the include would just be `class.php`.

Comment: Look at your include path in php.ini.

Comment: Or append it directly in your main script.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: Or you can define a constant to be used as a short path.

Comment: i've used composer .json to generate an autoloader in a vendor folder which uses psr-4. The index.php file is in /var/www/html/project/index.php. My sessions class is in /var/www/html/project/classes/session.php. I just want to be able to say. include classes/session.php

Answer (score 0):

Load Your Classes From Composer by using this in composer.json.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["/var/www/html/project/"]
    }
}
```

Composer will search classes for you int the mentioned directory.

Also you can add specific files in composer.json like this. you can pass multiple arguments on both cases.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["var/www/html/project/class.php"]
    }
}
```

Then all you need is just to include autoloader.php then composer will find classes for you for more reference see this section.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Comment: im using psr-4 which i had hoped would work, is there a solution for this? By using "use... blah. I'm refferencing my autoload, however i still can't find my files

Comment: First you need to add this line in your index.php if you want to include session in your index.php
 
require "../<path-to>/autoloader.php"

Now add use line like this 

use NameSpace\For\SessoinClass;

and now use SessionClass in index.php